# Py spark join on pipeline separated column

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two data frames which i want to join. The catch is the one of the tables have pipeline separated string on which one of the value is what I want to join with. How do I it in Pyspark. Below is an example
TABLE A has

```
+-------+--------------------+
|id     |      name          |
+-------+--------------------+
| 613760|123|test|test2      |
| 613740|456|ABC             |
| 598946|OMG|567             |
```

TABLE B has

```
+-------+--------------------+
|join_id|           prod_type|                           
+-------+--------------------+
| 123   |Direct De           |
| 456   |Direct              |
| 567   |In                  |
```

Expected Result - Join table A and Table B when there is a match with Table A's pipeline separated ID against Table B's value. For instance TableA.id - 613760 the name has 123|test and I want to join with table B's join ID 123 likewise 456 and 567.

Resultant Table

```
+--------------------+-------+
|      name          |join_Id|
+-------+------------+-------+
|123|test|test2      |123    |
|456|ABC             |456    |
|OMG|567             |567    |
```

Can someone help me solve this. I am relatively new to pyspark and I am learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to:

- `split` those "pipeline separated strings"
- then exploding those values into separated rows.
  `posexplode` would do that for you http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode
- from there an "inner join" and
- finally a "select" would do the rest of the trick.

See the code below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

#First create the dataframes to test solution
table_A = spark.createDataFrame([(613760, '123|test|test2' ), (613740, '456|ABC'), (598946, 'OMG|567' )], ["id", "name"])
# +-------+--------------------+
# |id     |      name          |
# +-------+--------------------+
# | 613760|123|test|test2      |
# | 613740|456|ABC             |
# | 598946|OMG|567             | 

table_B = spark.createDataFrame([('123', 'Direct De' ), ('456', 'Direct'), ('567', 'In' )], ["join_id", "prod_type"])
# +-------+--------------------+
# |join_id|           prod_type|                           
# +-------+--------------------+
# | 123   |Direct De           |
# | 456   |Direct              |
# | 567   |In                  | 

result = table_A \
    .select(
        'name',
        f.posexplode(f.split(f.col('name'),'\|')).alias('pos', 'join_id')) \
    .join(table_B, on='join_id', how='inner') \
    .select('name', 'join_id')

result.show(10, False)
# +--------------+-------+
# |name          |join_id|
# +--------------+-------+
# |123|test|test2|123    |
# |456|ABC       |456    |
# |OMG|567       |567    |
# +--------------+-------+
```

Hope that works. As you continue getting better in Pyspark. I would recommend you to go through the functions in `pyspark.sql.functions` and that would take your skills to the next level.

Comment: Thanks for this Jaime. I have a couple of questions - when we use posexplode will it explode into new rows? the reason i am asking is say my table_A has 1 million rows is posexplode the best way(or the only way) to do it?Thanks for the tip regarding the pyspark.sql.functions will definitely improve my skills there.

Comment: 1) Yes, `posexplode` would generate a row for each of the values separated by '|'. 
2) You need to parse through each of the values and to do that you need to split and to explode. Using `posexplode` is the best I could think of, you could also use lateral views but the memory footprint would be basically the same. Bottomline,I would not be too concerned with the memory or the processing needed for 1M records as a starting point, Hope that helps. Did the code work on your dataset?

Comment: Yes the functionality works. Just that i am trying to fit your code in my use case. I am trying to use the posexplode using with column but i keep getting the below error ``` The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got line_dropid_name ``` Below is my code ```df = gam_cons_df.withColumn('line_dropid_name',F.posexplode(F.split(F.col('line_item_name'),'\|')))```. Can you help me debug the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: the error means that the number of variables to fill (in your case 1 for `withColumn`) is less than the number of output variables generated by the function `F.posexplode(F.split(F.col('line_item_name'),'\|'))` (in this case the output are 2 variables). If you look at my code that is why I used `select` and `alias` instead of `withColumn`